# create-react-app is not including src and public folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I am trying to use create-react-app to create a new app but it is not working. The app is missing src, public folders
Terminal:
[image]

[image]

inside the app:
[image]

Comment: you should no longer install the `create-react-app` globally, just run it using `npx create-react-app my-app` as described in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It says you are using an outdated version of CRA that doesn't include templates. Update then try again.

Comment: In the tutorial, he is using the same version and his app is working fine.

Comment: @KaranYogi if you look at the end of your stack trace, global installs are also no longer supported. Just upgrade, and use the instructions from the main site.. shouldn't be much of a difference from the tutorial. Use this advice for all frameworks/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try the npx method. Run `npx create-react-app my-app`. It should install all the react files and folder in `my-app` folder.

Remember to run `cd my-app` to go in `my-app` folder and check if everything is fine by running `npm start`